# ODI 12C - Business Key auto increment

Tags: business-intelligence, oracle-data-integrator

Using ODI 12C, I Have a dimension with a combination of 2 Primary Keys. I Just want to perform a business key with auto-increment .

NOTE : - I Don't need a SCD behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this :

1 - Create sequence in Database Schema ( with no cache )

2 - Call it in the the needed mapping :

```
    <%=odiRef.getObjectName("L", "SEQ_NAME", "D")%>.nextval
```

3 - Set the mapping to be :

Active for inserts only, uncheck NOT NULL condition, EXCUTE ON HINT :TARGET

4 - PUT CKM TO : CKM SQL

5 - Run

Comment: That would work. I still prefer to use an ODI native sequence because it's easier to remember the syntax. Also if you need to change the name of the database sequence, you only need to update it in one place in ODI.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a sequence in your project or in the global objects. There are three types of it:

- Standard sequence, where the last value will be stored in the repository and ODI will increment it each time it retrieves a value.
- Specific sequence, same thing as above except that you choice in which table in which schema the value is stored
- Native sequence, which just use an underlying database sequence. This is the most popular choice as it will be a lot better for performance.

You can then call it using `:<SEQUENCE_NAME>_NEXTVAL`. For a native sequence it will get a new value for each row. For a standard or specific sequence it will give a new value for each row processed by the agent. So if you do row-by-row operation, it will give a new value for each row, but if you do batch operation, it will use the same value everywhere.

You can also call it using `#<SEQUENCE_NAME>_NEXTVAL` but this one will be substitued only once, before pushing the SQL on the database so all rows will have the same value.

If you use a native sequence on an Oracle database, you will have to set the *Execute On Hint* to *Target* so the sequence call is in the outermost select.

Comment: Hi Jerome , I tried to work with these different methods but it didn't work for me . I think it's because I don't work with logical run-time agent. 
when I run the job I get 5 5 5 5 5 then when I re-run I get 6 6 6 6 6

Comment: Have you tried using the native sequence with the colon syntax?